# Can minuscule chance of failure be useful in a proof?

Tags: probability, proof-writing

I have confirmed: $\left\lfloor\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{3^n-1}{2^n-1}\right\rfloor\text{ for }1< n\le500000,$ and that for $n\ge 500001,$ the chance of failure is less than $4.282484\times10^{-62470}$ percent.

Can this be useful in a proof?

Comment: No - it may be highly persuasive and there are similar arguments for [Goldbach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture), but it is not a proof.  (Incidentally, it is not true for $n=1$, while the sequence for $n \ge 2$ starts with a familiar $2,3,5,7,11,\ldots$)

Comment: It might be useful to know whether hypotheses are probable or plausible because it gives you an indication of how much effort and resources you should use on them. But the probability of a hypothesis being correct doesn't tell you it's impossible that the hypothesis is wrong and as Henry points out, it doesn't constitute a proof either.